# jQuery selectors and sIFR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sifr

I'm trying to use jQuery 1.3.1's :not selector with sIFR Ver. 3 Rev. 436.

I've enabled the use of jQuery selector's as per the instructions at the [sIFR Wiki](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/parseSelector), and basic selector's work which leads me to believe that sIFR is using the jQuery selectors.  More advanced jQuery selector's are not, though.

To enable jQuery selector's I removed the line in the minified sifr.js that started with `var parseSelector=(function()...` and replaced it with `var parseSelector = $;`.  I also have jQuery being included in the html file before sIFR.

## sifr-config.js

```
var mg = { src: '/static/mg.swf' }; 
sIFR.activate(mg);
sIFR.replace(mg, {
  selector: '#nav a',  #This works
  ...
})
sIFR.replace(mg, {
  selector: ':not(p)', #This doesn't work
  ...
});
```

My only other option is to hack up the CMS I'm using, so any guidance would be appreciated.

This is the log in response to Pekka.

```
selector: [object HTMLDocument]
selector: #top-nav a
selector: [object HTMLDocument]
selector:
selector: :contains(Disclaimer)
selector: [object HTMLDocument]
selector:
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'contains'.
[Break on this error] undefined
Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3
[Break on this error] var sIFR=new function(){var O=this;var E...(<br>)\s*/g,"$1"),primaryLink:k||{}}}};\nsifr.js (line 17)
selector: #top-nav a
selector: [object HTMLDocument]
selector:
selector: :contains(Disclaimer)
selector: [object HTMLDocument]
selector:
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that basic selectors work doesn't necessarily mean that JQuery's selectors are enabled. The first example (the one that works) is something that any browser can understand without JQUery. My guess is that the activating the use of JQuery selectors didn't work out. You might want to post the code you use to activate it.

Comment: That's a good point!  I edited my original post to include my changes to sIFR.

Comment: Are you loading JQuery before sIFR?

Comment: Yeah.  In the html file I've got jQuery loading before sIFR.  Both sIFR and jQuery are working properly on the page as well.

Comment: Strange. Maybe you can try a different JQuery specific filter like "contains:"? If that doesn't change anything, is there any way you can temporarily hack JQuery's `$` function and make it output each call to `console.log()` to see whether it gets executed?

Comment: The "contains" selector didn't work either, and I've added the log output to the original post.  

":not(p)"  gives the same kind of output except doesn't output any `Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element` type error.

Comment: What does sifr.js line 17 contain?

Comment: In the non-minified version it's `node.parentNode.appendChild(contentNode);`

Comment: What does your "contains" call look like? Do you have a leading colon `:contains`?

Comment: Yeah, my "contains" call was `selector: ':contains(Disclaimer)',`

Comment: I think "Disclaimer" needs to be in quotes. Can you add quotes?

Comment: No luck there either using `selector: ':contains("Disclaimer")',`  I also just tried updating to jQuery 1.3.2, which didn't change anything.

Comment: That's really, really odd. Can you confirm outside sifr that the selector works, for example by hiding all elements that match the selector?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried `$(':not(a)').css("visibility", "hidden");` right after sIFR's inclusion in the html file, and every element other than 'a' had `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: All right, then I don't know what to do. Sorry! You may want to open a bounty on this and see whether some JQuery guru wants to take a look at it. Alternatively, I would find it interesting to see what happens if you plug in your own wrapper function into SIFR that then in turn calls `$`. Anyway, that's what I'd try next.

Answer (score 0):

`:not(p)` looks like a particularly bad replacement to execute, can't you try something that would match fewer elements, especially nested elements?

Comment: My problem is that all of my elements have class names and id's that are generated dynamically.  I want to have the lower level elements use sIFR and the nested elements use normal Arial.  So I was hoping to use :not(nested element) as a filter.  The other solution I've come up with is to use sIFR to do the nested elements as Arial, but that's not my favorite solution.

Comment: sIFR replaces the entire content of whatever element you point it at. It sounds like you're using sIFR for the wrong purposes, it should be limited to headings really.